# VSCode REST CLIENT set shared / global environment variables programatically

Tags: visual-studio-code

In their (REST client) [documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client) has this

```
# @name login
POST {{baseUrl}}/api/login HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

name=foo&password=bar

###

@authToken = {{login.response.headers.X-AuthToken}}

# @name createComment
POST {{baseUrl}}/comments HTTP/1.1
Authorization: {{authToken}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

The first request is to log in and save the `authToken` to a variable and use that in other requests. The only problem here is this `authToken` variable can be accessed only within the same file. These variables are local scope to files.

I do want to inject it to the `$shared` environments, so then I can use token in other files as well. How do I do this with REST client plugin?

Comment: if there doc page does not explain this create an issue at there repository

Comment: See https://github.com/Huachao/vscode-restclient/issues/943 and https://github.com/Huachao/vscode-restclient/issues/845. I also ran into this use-case. Currently, it seems not possible yet, besides copying it manually to the .vscode settings.